# Long to HEX string

Tags: java, string, hex, converters, long-integer

I'm having trouble converting a hexadecimal number in a String to a long and then back again. Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void parseExperiment(){
    String str1 = "AA0F245C";
    long nr = Long.parseLong(str1, 16);
    String str2 = Double.toHexString(nr);
}
```

I want str2 to be the same as str1 but when I print str1, nr and str2 I get this:

```
str1: AA0F245C
nr: 2853119068
str2: 0x1.541e48b8p31
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: ...Why are you parsing a `long` with `Double.toHexString()`?

Answer (score 48):

Use [`Long.toHexString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString-long-) if you want to convert the `long` back again.

Converting a `long` to a hex string using [`Double.toHexString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString-double-) will give you the proper representation of a `double` which is different from that of a `long`.

Comment: Holy ****! I totally missed that! How did I mess up like that!?

Comment: I must know that **toHexString** just converts to unsigned values

Answer (score 12):

If you use `Long.toHexString(nr);` you will get correct answer

Comment: Holy ****! I totally missed that! How did I mess up like that!?